# React native drawer states

Tags: reactjs, native, drawer

I am new to react native, I used a [drawer menu](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer),  but how to know it's state, i.e, is there something like

```
_drawer.is_Open()
```

?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the particular control there, but a brief reading of that documentation suggests `_drawer.open`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can just examine the _open property.

```
_drawer._open
```

https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer/blob/master/index.js#L18